# How Twitter Follow and UnFollow button works in Android app

Tags: android, button, twitter, broadcastreceiver, twitter-follow

I need to implement a similar flow like Twitter Follow button in my Android application.
I just want to know what happens in the background when the Follow button is clicked?
Below are the questions regarding Twitter Follow button:

1. How Twitter has created the flow, how do they handle request to server without affecting the current UI experience?
2. How does it manage when I click the Follow button when there is no Internet connection available?
3. Does it use any Broadcast receiver after processing the service in the background to handle the result?

Comment: Get a job at Twitter and ask them. Nobody else can speak authoritatively about what Twitter does.

Comment: Have you read https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/friendships/create ?